# Поиск в List<double> ближайшего большего и меньшего вещественного значения

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в `List<double>` (список сортированный) найти ближайшие большее и меньше вещественного значение и их индексы в списке, и учесть случай когда число есть и его нет.

Есть вот такой список:

```
List<double> heightList = new List<double>() {
    5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0 };
```

Входное число:

```
double number = 5.5;
```

Правильный ответ при таком будет меньшее ближайшее 5.0 с индексом 0, большее ближайшее 10.0 с индексом 1.

Через бинарный поиск попытался вот так сделать

[image: функция с бинарным поиском]

Comment: Если список сортированный, почитайте про алгоритм двоичного поиска

Comment: Реализуйте бинарный поиск самостоятельно, без использования каких-то готовых функций. Смотрите метод деления пополам

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку у Вас очень много кода. Решил дать вам такой алгоритм.

Так [как](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)

> Двоичный (бинарный) поиск (также известен, как метод деления пополам
> или дихотомия) — классический алгоритм поиска элемента в
> **отсортированном** массиве (векторе), использующий дробление массива на
> половины. Используется в информатике, вычислительной математике и
> математическом программировании.

1. Добавляете ваше число `number`, вокруг которого идет поиск в список `heightList`.
2. Сортируете `heightList`.
3. Бинарным поиском ищите своё число `number`. ([List.BinarySearch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-5.0))
4. Найдя индекc `index`, смотрите два элемента, до `index - 1, index - 2` и после `index + 1, index + 2`итого, максимум рассматриваете 4 элемента в случае `index > 1` и `index < heightList.Count - 1`. Иначе даже не рассматриваете индекс, который вышел за рамки списка.
5. Выбираете ближайший к вашему числу по модулю.

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеке дотнета, насколько я понимаю, нет готового метода для бинарного поиска самого левого или самого правого элемента (подобно `lower_bound` и `upper_bound` в STL). Это полезно в том случае, если список может содержать много дубликатов.

Однако можно [заглянуть в Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Duplicate_elements) и реализовать нужные методы на основе псевдокода:

```
function binary_search_leftmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else:
            R := m
    return L

function binary_search_rightmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] > T:
            R := m
        else:
            L := m + 1
    return R - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

я думаю что можно отсортировать по отклонению от искомого значения, это не столь быстро как бинарный поиск, но даёт простой код и возможность получить несколько ближайших значений.

```
heightList.sort((a,b)=>Math.Abs(a - number) < Math.Abs(b - number) ? -1 : 1)
heightList[0] // искомая запись
```